# Conditional formatting based on snother cell

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a list of due dates in column j and a list of dates when the reports were submitted in column k

If tge due date is less than today (as in its now overdue) i want to put some formatting on thst overdue date to make it stand out but as soon as the submitted date is filled out i want the formatting to return to normal

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your due date starts on row 2. Select all the due dates and add a conditional formatting rule as follows:

`=AND(I2<TODAY(), ISBLANK(J2))`

and select the highlight format you want.

Comment: There’s cells in the column that still have the highlight on them despite the completion date being filled in and some cell where the date is in the future with no completion date but it’s highlighted as if it was in the past. Also cells with a date in the past with no completion date which should have the highlight and don’t

Comment: Are u using column J and K as you mentioned in the question? If so, please replace I2 with J2 and J2 with K2 (my bad).  Otherwise, please have a screen capture of your table (together with the column headers).